# How to run Google maps application on kindle fire

Tags: android, google-maps, kindle-fire

I have developed Google map application, it is working fine in mobile devices.
But in kindle fire it is not working, when i remove the `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`
from the manifest file the app is working good in kindle fire.
My Question is how to run the application with Google maps in kindle fire...

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps doesn't exist on the Fire. You need to use an alternative mapping library, perhaps OpenStreetMaps - there are Android integrations for it.
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

Or Bing Maps.
http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/